# How to create a custom control which inherits CollectionView?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, maui

I am trying to implement a custom control which binds to a list of element and displays them as a scrollable list. It will ultimately be displayed as a page bottom sheet and allow for expanding + scrolling. For that purpose I decided to base the control on CollectionView, and ideally I would like the control to not be bound to a XAML file.

The issue is that my control just does not show anything, not sure what I am missing here and the code has been taken directly from Microsoft documentation of CollectionView.

```
public class CustomCollectionView : CollectionView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MonkeysProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Monkeys), typeof(ObservableCollection<MonkeyViewModel>), typeof(CustomCollectionView));
    public ObservableCollection<MonkeyViewModel> Monkeys
    {
        get => (ObservableCollection<MonkeyViewModel>)GetValue(MonkeysProperty);
        set => SetValue(MonkeysProperty, value);
    }

    public CustomCollectionView()
    {
        Monkeys = new ObservableCollection<MonkeyViewModel>()
        {
            new MonkeyViewModel("Monkey1"), new MonkeyViewModel("Monkey2")
        };

        var linearItemsLayout = new LinearItemsLayout(ItemsLayoutOrientation.Vertical)
        {
            ItemSpacing = 8,
        };

        ItemsLayout = linearItemsLayout;

        this.SetBinding(ItemsSourceProperty, "Monkeys");

        ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            Grid grid = new Grid { Padding = 10, BackgroundColor = new Color(255, 0, 0) };
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });


            Label nameLabel = new Label { FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold };
            nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");    

            grid.Add(nameLabel, 1, 0);
            return grid;
        });
    }

public partial class MonkeyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _name;

    public MonkeyViewModel(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

And the way I use it:

```
 <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Label Text="A"/>
    <local:CustomCollectionView/>
    <Label Text="B"/>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

Thanks for any input on this

Comment: You are not setting the BindingContext

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the BindingContext should be here, as I am trying to replicate this code: <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"> which works fine (assuming CollectionView.ItemTemplate is set)

Comment: you are binding `this.SetBinding(ItemsSourceProperty, "Monkeys");` to the `Monkeys` property of your class, so `BindingContext = this;`

Comment: I put BindingContext = new MonkeysViewModel(); in the code behind of the page where you declare the custom control.

Comment: You want your control to bind to its own Monkeys property

Comment: Oh I understand now, many thanks for getting back to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the line in the constructor for custom control: `CustomCollectionView` to make it worked:

```
BindingContext = this;
```

**CustomCollectionView.cs**:

```
public class CustomCollectionView : CollectionView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MonkeysProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Monkeys), typeof(ObservableCollection<MonkeyViewModel>), typeof(CustomCollectionView));
    public ObservableCollection<MonkeyViewModel> Monkeys
    {
        get => (ObservableCollection<MonkeyViewModel>)GetValue(MonkeysProperty);
        set => SetValue(MonkeysProperty, value);
    }

    public CustomCollectionView()
    {
        Monkeys = new ObservableCollection<MonkeyViewModel>()
        {
            new MonkeyViewModel("Monkey1"), new MonkeyViewModel("Monkey2")
        };

        var linearItemsLayout = new LinearItemsLayout(ItemsLayoutOrientation.Vertical)
        {
            ItemSpacing = 8,
        };

        ItemsLayout = linearItemsLayout;

        this.SetBinding(ItemsSourceProperty, "Monkeys");

        ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            Grid grid = new Grid { Padding = 10, BackgroundColor = new Color(255, 0, 0) };
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });


            Label nameLabel = new Label { FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold };
            nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");    

            grid.Add(nameLabel, 1, 0);
            return grid;
        });
        //key is here
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]